# Delphi Interfacing

Tags: delphi, interface

Evening all,

I am attempting to unit test some of my Delphi code using dUnit and PascalMock.

There is a large amount of legacy code that isn't at all interfaced, that also contain parameters passing in objects of itself, for example:

```
TSelf = Class
  Function Hello(self: TSelf);
end;
```

I have then attempted to apply an interface to TSelf:

```
ISelf = Interface(IInterface)
  Function Hello(self: TSelf)
end;

TSelf = Class(TInterfacedObject, ISelf)
  Function Hello(self: TSelf);
end;
```

This is obviously then failing because "TSelf" is undefined, these are large objects with many functions that use TSelf as a parameter, is my only option to go through and change these to TObject? And cast them to TSelf within the method?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as it is currently preventing me from being able to automatically test.

Alternatively is there a mocking framework that doesn't require an interface?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward class declaration

```
type
  TSelf = class;

  ISelf = Interface
    procedure Hello(ASelf: TSelf);
  end;

  TSelf = Class(TInterfacedObject, ISelf)
    procedure Hello(ASelf: TSelf);
  end;
```

But in that case full `TSelf` class declaration must be defined within same type declaration section.

As side note, using `self` as parameter name is confusing, and that code cannot be compiled, as well as function that does not have result type.

Comment: This works, thank you very much.

The code examples I gave were just off the top of my head to try and give a rough example of what I was trying to achieve, however, your comments are correct and I will take them on board with any future questions I make.

Thanks again!